# How Can I Limit The Number of JQuery Cloned Divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, clone

I'm new to JQuery and I'm having some trouble with the Clone() function.

My question is how can I limit the number of times the answers  can be cloned?
Would I declare a variable and run it through a loop until the desired number is reached?

**Here is the .aspx**

```
> <div id="answer_wrapper">
>     <div id="answer">
>         <h3 class="new">Answer 1</h3>
>         <asp:TextBox ID="QuestionAnswer1" runat="server" CssClass="form" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>
>     </div>
>     <h3 class="new">Answer 2</h3>
>     <asp:TextBox ID="QuestionAnswer2" runat="server" CssClass="form" Width="300px"></asp:TextBox>
> </div> <!-- end answer_wrapper -->
> <br />
> <asp:Button ID="ga" runat="server" CssClass="button_add_question" style="border: 0px;" />
> <a id="foo" href="#">Duplicate</a>

> <script type="text/javascript">
>     $('#foo').click(function () {
>     $('#answer').clone().appendTo('#answer_wrapper');
>     });
> </script>
```

Any help would be much appreciated as I don't really know how to approach this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either limit the number of divs cloned by setting a var outside click event and increasing its value or you can count the divs number.

I expect you want to change or remove the id too.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var count = 1;
    $('#foo').click(function () {
        if(count < 5) {
            $('#answer').clone().attr({ 'id': 'answer' + count }).appendTo('#answer_wrapper');
            //$('#answer').clone().removeAttr('id').appendTo('#answer_wrapper'); // remove the attribute
            count++;
        }
    });
</script>
```

counting divs:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#foo').click(function () {
        if($('.answer').length < 5) { // Hope you add a class to the answer
            $('#answer').clone().addClass('answer').removeAttr('id').appendTo('#answer_wrapper');
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Great solution. Simple and tidy. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your code is going to cause multiple elements with the same ID to be created, which isn't ideal, but to answer your question, maybe do this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var limit = 10;
     $('#foo').click(function () {
         if($('#answer').length < limit) {
             $('#answer').clone().appendTo('#answer_wrapper');
         }
     });
</script>
```

Comment: You mentioned parts of the code that will duplicate ID's.
Which part should i be concerned with?